# Azure B2C EditProfile custom policy without Signing In first

Tags: azure, customization, edit, azure-ad-b2c, user-profile

Right now the `ProfileEdit.xml` file that comes with [active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) asks the user to sign in before actually letting them get to the Edit Profile page.

The use case I'm trying to accomplish is a little bit different. The user is already signed in to the app and there's a button `Edit Profile` that when clicked will take the user to the Edit Profile page. That is, there should be no Sign in again.

My app allows the user to sign in using: `Facebook` and `Local Account Signin`. The custom ProfileEdit B2C policy should know which one the user used to login and just redirect the user to the ProfileEdit policy directly.

I tried messing up with the `ProfileEdit` Technical Profile but the mods I did didn't work.

Can anyone more experienced with Azure B2C custom policies let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal, imagine someone got to the profile edit link and bookmarked it. Then logged out. Then launched profile edit -> you **need** them to login, otherwise things break.
So this is actually working perfectly already, just that you will get Single Sign On, such that once you have used the Sign In journey, the Profile Edit journey will skip the sign in step.

You can test it like this:
1. Open a new browser, and use the sign in journey, login and complete.
2. Open a new tab, and paste the Profile Edit link, **remove the prompt=login** query parameter.
3. Execute the link, you are taken straight to modifying your profile page, rather than seeing a sign in page.

Comment: Yep man... you're absolutely right. I copied the policy link from Azure portal directly and it had `prompt=login` parameter. I just removed `prompt=login` from the URL and now it goes right to the Edit Profile page. Thanks for your detailed steps.